# Horizontal list of UIViews with wrapping but no scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to show list of UIViews horizontally one after another  and I want them to wrap if there is not enough space on the line.

Case 1 : enough space on the line

```
| [VIEW1] [VIEW2] [VIEW3]         |
```

Case 2 : not enough space on the line

```
| [VIEW1] [VIEW2]                 |
| [VIEW3 IS TOO LONG SO IT WRAP]  |
```

It's *exactly* what do UICollectionView + flowLayout BUT I don't want any scroll. My question could be "how to disable scroll and show all the content of a UICollectionView ?"

Thanks.

NB : Of course the number of views is dynamic, and all these views have different width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an explicit height constraint on the `collectionView` and set its height to:

```
self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
```

After the collection view was reloaded (you want the `contentSize` be calculated already).

Since the `collectionView` will be as high as its content, no scrolling will be needed.

Of course, you want to constrain left and right sides of the collection view properly.

Comment: Sounds good, but the contentSize.height is much to small in my tests. I guess since the collection has no height constraint in the begining, he did not try to ask the datasource for content, an thus not increment his content height ?

Comment: @Neekobus well, you can test your hypothesis by setting the height constraint at the beginning to some constant value, call setNeedsLayout, layoutIfNeeded, then reloadData, then again setNeedsLayout, layoutIfNeeded, and after that check out the contentSize.. after this it has to be calculated properly

Comment: Yep that's just what I've done. Setting a constant (big) constraint before loading the data and update the constant with the real contentSize after do the work. The only drawback is that you can see the first size while the data are loaded. Investigating this.

Comment: @Neekobus another approach (more consistent) might be implementing intrinsic content size for the collection view, but that would require much more coding

Comment: That's exactly what I try to avoid :)

Comment: Updating the size constraint just after the "reload" is not always good (may be too early). So I use an observer on the "contentSize" of the collectionView and wait for the final size to ajust my contraint ! Now it's working. Thanks.

Comment: @Neekobus nice!

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView` so you can modify the `collectionView.contentSize` to be the less than the width (or height, depending which way you don't want it to scroll) of its parent View and it won't scroll.